# Nested foreach() messing up

Tags: asp.net, foreach, webforms

Good Day, guys.

I'm currentl making a full page overlay for navigation and I've been trying to figure out this problem for the past 2 days regarding my nested foreach() loops.

I have these pages which may be linked with posts. and here is what I'm trying to achieve:

`Home Page
Technologies Page
Post 1/ Post 2/ Post3
Contact Us Page
About Us Page`

But what I'm getting is:

`Home Page
Technologies Page
Post 1/ Post 2/ Post3
Contact Us Page
Post 1/ Post 2/ Post3
About Us Page
Post 1/ Post 2/ Post3`

Here are my code:

```
  public DataTable GetMain()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Id,Title,Slug from Pages";

        SqlCommand SQLComm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter SQLAd = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLComm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLAd.Fill(dt);
        return dt;            
    }

   private void GetAll()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        HyperLink newhyperlink = new HyperLink();
        Label newlabel = new Label();

        foreach (DataRow row in GetMain().Rows)
        {
            newlabel.ID = "li";
            MainMenu.Controls.Add(newlabel);
            newlabel.Text = @"<li class""dropdown"" data-toggle=""collapse""";
            newlabel = new Label();

            newhyperlink.ID = "Main";
            MainMenu.Controls.Add(newhyperlink);
            newhyperlink.Text = row["Title"].ToString();
            newhyperlink.NavigateUrl = row["Slug"].ToString();
            newhyperlink = new HyperLink();
            html.Append("></li>");
            html.Append("<ul class=\"list-group\">");

            var sql2 = "SELECT po.Id as PostId, po.Slug as PostSlug, po.Title as PostTitle, pa.Slug as PageSlug, pa.Id as PageId FROM Posts po " +
                       "LEFT JOIN PagesPostsMap m ON po.Id = m.PostId " +
                       "LEFT JOIN Pages pa ON m.PageId = pa.Id  " + 
                       "WHERE pa.Id = "+row["Id"] + "";

            SqlDataAdapter SQLAd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2, con);
            SQLAd.Fill(dt2);



            foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
            {
                object value = row2["PostId"];
                if (value != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    if (row["Id"] != row2["PageId"])
                    {
                        newlabel.ID = "li";
                        MainMenu.Controls.Add(newlabel);
                        newlabel.Text = @"<li class""dropdown-menu""";
                        newlabel = new Label();

                        newhyperlink.ID = "Sub" + i.ToString();
                        MainMenu.Controls.Add(newhyperlink);
                        newhyperlink.Text = row2["PostTitle"].ToString();
                        newhyperlink.NavigateUrl = row2["PageSlug"].ToString() + "/" + row2["PostSlug"].ToString();
                        newhyperlink = new HyperLink();


                        newlabel.ID = "li";
                        MainMenu.Controls.Add(newlabel);
                        newlabel.Text = "</li>";
                        newlabel = new Label();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

I'm sorry if the the classes and stuff are not adding up. I'm still trying to figure out how css and JS works.

And thank for helping me.

Comment: Hi, are you using visual studio?

Comment: @chrillelundmark. Yes.

Comment: That question was actually irrelevant, at first i thought there was something wrong with your SQL but then I read your question properly. My thought was if it was possible to run SQL in Server explorer and see how many rows you produced but I'm pretty sure you produce the correct amount of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable GetMain()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Id,Title,Slug from Pages";

        SqlCommand SQLComm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter SQLAd = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLComm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLAd.Fill(dt);
        return dt;            
    }

   private void GetAll()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        HyperLink newhyperlink = new HyperLink();
        Label newlabel = new Label();

        foreach (DataRow row in GetMain().Rows)
        {
            newlabel.ID = "li";
            MainMenu.Controls.Add(newlabel);
            newlabel.Text = @"<li class""dropdown"" data-toggle=""collapse""";
            newlabel = new Label();

            newhyperlink.ID = "Main";
            MainMenu.Controls.Add(newhyperlink);
            newhyperlink.Text = row["Title"].ToString();
            newhyperlink.NavigateUrl = row["Slug"].ToString();
            newhyperlink = new HyperLink();
            html.Append("></li>");
            html.Append("<ul class=\"list-group\">");

            var sql2 = "SELECT po.Id as PostId, po.Slug as PostSlug, po.Title as PostTitle, pa.Slug as PageSlug, pa.Id as PageId FROM Posts po " +
                       "JOIN PagesPostsMap m ON po.Id = m.PostId " +
                       "JOIN Pages pa ON m.PageId = pa.Id  " + 
                       "WHERE pa.Id = "+row["Id"] + "";

            SqlDataAdapter SQLAd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2, con);
            SQLAd.Fill(dt2);



            foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
            {

                        newlabel.ID = "li";
                        MainMenu.Controls.Add(newlabel);
                        newlabel.Text = @"<li class""dropdown-menu""";
                        newlabel = new Label();

                        newhyperlink.ID = "Sub" + i.ToString();
                        MainMenu.Controls.Add(newhyperlink);
                        newhyperlink.Text = row2["PostTitle"].ToString();
                        newhyperlink.NavigateUrl = row2["PageSlug"].ToString() + "/" + row2["PostSlug"].ToString();
                        newhyperlink = new HyperLink();


                        newlabel.ID = "li";
                        MainMenu.Controls.Add(newlabel);
                        newlabel.Text = "</li>";
                        newlabel = new Label();

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: @SlicedBread sorry I didnt notice the other loop above. will it be ok if you could post a sample screenshot result of this script so that we could check its table reference. 

SELECT TOP 10  po.*,
        '|',
        m*,
        '|',
        pa.*
FROM    Posts po
        LEFT JOIN PagesPostsMap m ON po.Id = m.PostId
        LEFT JOIN Pages pa ON m.PageId = pa.Id

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. and it can't run the script

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually just doing what you tell it to do. For every row in your GetMain, you order everything in your dt2 (datatable2). If you want what you try to achive, you have to set a condition and put your second foreach into that condition.

```
if(tech parts row)
{
    "your second foreach"
}
```

If I missunderstand anything, feel free to add more info